# Vuejs $emit doesnt work in some part of a function, and in other part works

Tags: vue.js, emit

I am using vuejs3 and trying to emit event from a child component.

**child Component**

```
<input type="button" v-if="edition_mode" @click="cancel()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Annuler">
[...]
cancel(){
    if(this.new_sav){
        this.$emit('test')
    }else{
        console.log('else')
        this.$emit('test')
    }
},
```

**Parent Component**

```
<div v-if="creation_form">
    <h4>Ajout Nouveau Sav</h4>
    <sav-form
    :initial_data="null" 
    :li_product="li_product" 
    :new_sav="true" 
    :customer_id="data.customer.id"
    @action="form_action"
    @test="test()"/>
</div>
[...]
test(){
    console.log('test emit works')
}
```

When cancel() is executed, in the if case $emit() works correctly, but in the else case, only 'else' is printed and $emit is not executed. What I am doing wrong here ?

I also have several buttons in child component, in the same div, that all call differents function but some function 'can' emit event and other can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what issue you are facing but it is working fine in the below code snippet. Please have a look and let me know if any further clarification/discussion required.

Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div><button @click="cancel()">Trigger emit event from child!</button></div>',
  data() {
    return {
        isValid: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    cancel: function() {
      this.isValid = !this.isValid;
      if (this.isValid) {
        console.log('valid');
        this.$emit('test');
      } else {
        console.log('not valid');
        this.$emit('test')
      }
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    getTestEvent() {
      console.log('Emit event from child triggered!');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <child @test="getTestEvent"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I tried to implements your code in my app and its work so i guess the problem comes from my parent component.

Comment: @kalyklos Glad it works for you. Please do accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: You've imported vue v2 in your final code snippet whereas the OP refers to vue 3. Does the same code work in vue v3?

Comment: @HowardShaw Yes it will work for Vue3 as well as it is just regarding emitting an event from child to parent.

Comment: I can answer my own question .. yes it does

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.
I use Vuex to store authenticated status of the user and my mistake was to use `v-if="isAuth"` attribute in parent component and the child component set `isAuth` to false through the store so `this.$emit()` doesn't work anymore.

Parent Component:

```html
<login-form @onLogin="onLoginHandler" v-if="!isAuth" />
```

Child Component:

```js
methods: {
   example() {
      [...]
      const response = await axios.post("/login", data);
      if (response.status === 200) {
         // under the hood isAuth is set to True;
         this.$store.dispatch("SET_AUTH", true);
      }

      // Doesn't work anymore because the parent component v-if is now False.
      this.$emit("onLogin", response.data);
   }
}
```